# Can't find the IP address of external DNS server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed 2012 R2 and Active Directory.  As part of this DNS was installed and is working as expected.

My question is where to find the IP address of the external DNS server I'm using.  I expected to see it in the Forward Lookup Zone but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: Isn't the DNS server that the server itself uses set in the static IP address settings? Not in the AD settings, but in the static IP settings for that server....

Comment: The DNS server should be using root hints?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What DNS server are you looking for exactly?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the internal DNS then you are NOT using any external DNS servers. Your server contains an IP based list of root name servers which are first contacted for unknown domains. This in effect turning you machine into a resolver for domains other then ones it is  a primary for.